# d3 force graph not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

So, as the title says i'm working on a `d3` force graph in a `flask` template.

The error I get is:

```
uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

this is the json as returned from {{qr|tojson}}:

```
{"fteam": "Juventus FC", "toteam": "Calcio Padova"}
```

please note that {{qr|tojson}} comes from jinja2s templating system, it literally means "take qr and print it as json", that said

```
var json = {"fteam": "Juventus FC", "toteam": "Calcio Padova"}
```

Here's the code:

```
var width = 760,
  height = 500

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .gravity(.05)
  .distance(100)
  .charge(-100)
  .size([width, height]);

var json = {{ qr | tojson }}

force
  .nodes(json.nodes)
  .links(json.links)
  .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(json.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(json.nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .call(force.drag);

node.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
  .attr("x", -8)
  .attr("y", -8)
  .attr("width", 16)
  .attr("height", 16);

node.append("text")
  .attr("dx", 12)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name
  });

force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
});
```

Comment: Send us your JSON please. This line is really weird `var json = {{qr|tojson}}`. Are you using some sort of templating?

Comment: This error means that your data is mal-formed and not what `d3` expects.  As @caulitomaz says, **edit your question** to include your JSON.

Comment: @Mark i've edited the question including the json code, sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for interesting :)

Comment: @caulitomaz same for you, stack doesn't allow me to tag you both .-.

Comment: You have told d3 to use `json.nodes` for nodes and `json.links` for links, yet your `json` variable does not contain either objects. Your JSON should have two objects: `nodes`, which is an array of objects contains the `x` and `y` coordinates of each node, and `links`, which is an array of objects containing the `source` and `target` nodes, identified by index. Your JSON file [should look something like the one in this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558#graph.json).

Comment: @Terry that's a good point XD
Sorry but it's my first time with D3, there are no commented tutorials for what i need, and i'm randomly trying to make it work.
So, assumed that i will always have a json like the one in the question, how can i make it work?
I really just need a graph with linked dots, preferably with force.

Comment: Did you check the link? It contains an entire example for you to base your code on.

Comment: @Terry i saw it now, thank you XD
still i don't know the right way to edit the code to use dynamic json generated by flask instead of a static file...